# Trying to copy a file to certain subfolders using command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, copy, subdirectory

I'm trying to find out how to use command line (with the intent to create a batch file so I can do this automatically) to copy a single file into multiple subfolders,

The current folder setup is:

```
C:\MainFolder:

DestinationFolder1
       Sending
       Receiving
DestinationFolder2
       Sending
       Receiving
DestinationFolder3
       Sending
       Receiving
```

How would I send `C:\Example.txt` to the `Sending` directory in each Destination folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmdline version:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s /ad C:\Mainfolder ^| findstr /i "Sending"') do copy "C:\Example.txt" "%~i" /Y
```

Batch file version (only difference is double `%`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /ad C:\Mainfolder ^| findstr /i "Sending"') do copy "C:\Example.txt" "%%~i" /Y
```

It simply runs a `dir` command with search function on each folder inside of `C:\Mainfolder`. Using `findstr` it only gets the folders that contains `Sending` then copies the file to it.

for more help on the above commands, open `cmd` and type:

```
for /?
dir /?
findstr /?
```

Comment: Thank you so much! tried it out with my test folders! Gonna make a couple changes and try to put it into practice!